# Error using glossaries package trying to compile with makeindex

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

I am having a trouble when I try running the `makeindex` command. I get the following error message:

```
Index style file Tesis.ist not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

I am using Texmaker, and suppose I have to change configuration but don't know how or where. How can I correct this error?

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{BOOK}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}

 \usepackage{glossaries} 

 \newglossaryentry{feromona} {name=feromona,  description={blablalb}}
 \makeglossaries

 \title{GLOSARIO}
 \author{Eli}
 \date{\today}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \section{Ejemplo}

 \gls{feromona} 

 \printglossaries

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of running `makeindex` by hand, why don't you just use `makeglossaries`?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The error message says that `makeindex` can't find the file called `Tesis.ist`. This could mean that you haven't used `\makeglossaries` in the preamble.

Comment: I have used \makeglossaries, but I get the error

Comment: @Eli: Your document is not compilable for users here, since they know nothing of `paquetes` and of `glosario.tex`.

Comment: Tip (not related to the problem): if you use `\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}` you don't need the `\addcontentsline` command. Did your document compile okay with `latex` before you tried to use `makeindex`?

Comment: Try to run `makeglossaries` on your main file (without ending). This little script takes care of the makeindex call. Not sure if you need a running perl install.